# Display Duplicate values in a XML file using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am completely new to XSLT. Below Input file has a duplicate values in the tag  and my requirement is to display all the duplicate values of `<Rip>` in the `<PGS>` using XSLT.

`<Rip>` is the random values and it will be duplicated in another tag. We need to identify where `<RIP>` tag value match with duplicates.

How to display only the duplicated tag `<PGS>` using XSLT?

Input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rows>
    <PGS>
    <Rip>93S981371 </Rip>
    <Settled>NO</Settled>
    <MaturityDate>1/1/2025</MaturityDate>
    <RemainingFace>105000000</RemainingFace>
    <CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
    </PGS>
    <PGS>
    <Rip>02R030483 </Rip>
    <Settled>YES</Settled>
    <MaturityDate>9/8/2025</MaturityDate>
    <Remaining-Face>285000000</RemainingFace>
    <CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
    </PGS>
    <PGS>
    <Rip>77344444 </Rip>
    <Settled>YES</Settled>
    <MaturityDate>9/8/2025</MaturityDate>
    <Remaining-Face>285000000</RemainingFace>
    <CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
    </PGS>
    <PGS>
    <Rip>02R030483 </Rip>
    <Settled>NO</Settled>
    <MaturityDate>9/8/2025</MaturityDate>
    <Remaining-Face>285000000</RemainingFace>
    <CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
    </PGS>
    <PGS>
    <Rip>93S981371 </Rip>
    <Settled>YES</Settled>
    <MaturityDate>1/1/2025</MaturityDate>
    <Remaining-Face>405000000</RemainingFace>
    <CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
    </PGS>
</Rows>
```

Expected output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Rows>
<PGS>
<Rip>93S981371 </Rip>
<Settled>NO</Settled>
<MaturityDate>1/1/2025</MaturityDate>
<RemainingFace>105000000</RemainingFace>
<CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
</PGS>
 <PGS>
<Rip>93S981371 </Rip>
<Settled>YES</Settled>
<MaturityDate>1/1/2025</MaturityDate>
<Remaining-Face>405000000</RemainingFace>
<CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
</PGS>
<PGS>
<Rip>02R030483 </Rip>
<Settled>YES</Settled>
<MaturityDate>9/8/2025</MaturityDate>
<Remaining-Face>285000000</RemainingFace>
<CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
</PGS>
</PGS>
<Rip>02R030483 </Rip>
<Settled>NO</Settled>
<MaturityDate>9/8/2025</MaturityDate>
<Remaining-Face>285000000</RemainingFace>
<CurrentFace>0</CurrentFace>
</PGS>
```

Comment: Wellcome to Stack Overflow. This is a place to ask questions, not a coding service. If you are "completely new to XSLT", I suggest you learn the basics first, then ask a *specific* question you are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is this:

Start by defining a **key** that identifies a `PGS` by its `Rip` value, e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="pgs" match="PGS" use="Rip" />
```

Then match (or copy) `PGS` elements that have more than one "related" value:

```
PGS[count(key('pgs', Rip)) > 1]
```

i.e. they match another `PGS`  element beside themselves.